# deploy the mezzanine supported by django with model wsgi under python3

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, mezzanine

thank you for reading this question, I have confused with this for a long time after many searches on google.

Recently I want to deploy a python3 + mezzanine + apache2 + wsgi site into ubuntu 14 server, I am new to python but that's cool to take something new. OK, all the settings are below:

- I installed the mezzanine in the virtual environment for python3 using **virtualenv**

  `virtualenv venv`
- then installed the mezzanine, and create a database, and Collectstatic command for the static files after active the **venv**
- write my site's **wsgi.py**

  ```
  #!/home/edgarzeng/venv/bin python

  #I found the below two doesn't make sense and comment both.
  #activate_env = "/home/edgarzeng/venv/bin/activate_this.py"`
  #execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

  import os
  import sys
  import site

  PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]

  site.addsitedir('/home/edgarzeng/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
  sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, ".."))

  settings_module = "%s.settings" % PROJECT_DIRNAME
  os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings_module)

  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  application = get_wsgi_application()
  ```
- create a site config file **myblog.conf** under sites-avaliable folder

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerAdmin mzrtry@163.com
      ServerName blog.edgarzeng.net
      #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      WSGIDaemonProcess blog.edgarzeng.net python-path=/home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/:/home/edgarzeng/venv/
      WSGIScriptAlias / /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/wsgi.py process-group=blog.edgarzeng.net

      <Directory /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog>
          <Files wsgi.py>
                  Require all granted
          </Files>
      </Directory>

      Alias /static/ /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/static/
      <Directory /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/static>
              Require all granted
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/logs/error.log
      LogLevel debug
      CustomLog /home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/logs/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- also, the mod_wsgi installed and chown the www-data:www-data -R to the **myblog**(my web project name)

You can go to [my site](http://blog.edgarzeng.net), that's ok for the index page, but there are problems to click some sub menus like *about*, *team*, etc. And the main cause looks like the python execute linked to some place wrong

```
No module named html.entities
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://blog.edgarzeng.net/about/
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named html.entities
Exception Location: /home/edgarzeng/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py in <module>, line 11
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/home/edgarzeng/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/edgarzeng/blog.edgarzeng.net/myblog/..']
Server time:    Wed, 10 Dec 2014 10:05:26 +0800
```

You will found this error information just when you click any sub menus. As what I think that the python execute environment is linked to python3, because I defined the virtual environment for python3 both in **wsgi.py** and the **myblog.conf**. But I don't know what wrong with these settings for a long time.

Actually I do these follow the [blog](https://vimmaniac.com/blog/bangal/mezzanine-configuration-with-apache-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu/)

Please help me ,

Thanks advanced.

Comment: Can you try explicitly specifying the python executable to be python3 with the -p flag when creating your virtual environment?

Comment: I didn't realize that problem, but when I active the venv, with the command **python**, it shows me the version of python is 3.4.0. Ok, I also will try your suggestion.

Comment: I have created a new virtualenv with th flag -p, but the same error it shows. May be there are some other settings are wrong.

Comment: This may help: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I think this is not what I want, it's true the error that I got is that the web is running the python3 version of code under the python2. So, the problem is that I can not make the python executable be python3, that will be ok if I know the way to set python3 to my default running environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have known what's wrong with my site. It's very simple, the key problem is that the version of the installed mod_wsgi is 2.X. Actually it works after I done the below action:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

e...